# Two approaches to duality in TVS: dual pairing versus "canonical" dual. Are they equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces, duality-theorems

I have been reading about the basics of duality in Topological Vector Spaces and I have met two different approaches.

**Treves**

- starts from a TVS $(E,\iota)$, which determines the *set* of continuous
  linear forms on $E$: $E'_\iota$. Then he describes a technique to
  topologize $E'_\iota$ through *polar topologies on* $E'_\iota$.
- He then describes an analogous way to topologise the *set* of
  continuous linear maps $\phi:(E,\tau)\rightarrow (F,\sigma)$ where $(E,\tau)$
  and $(F,\sigma)$ are two TVS, let us call this *set* $L(E,F)$. This is
  evidently a generalization of the previous case, if one considers 
  $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with the usual topology.
- Characherizes which topologies $\tau$ on $E$ are such that $E'_\iota=E'_\tau$. Hence, which way of retopologizing a TVS $E$ preserve its topological dual. He calls these topologies compatible with a duality and proves that any topology on a locally convex TVS $E$ can be seen as such: it is the topology of uniform conergence on equicontinuous subsets of $E'$.
- Moreover he shows that $\sigma(E,E')$, the topology of convergence on finite sets of $E'$ is the coarsest to achieve the result and moreover he shows we can always embed $E$ in $(E'_\sigma)'$.
- Proves the Mackey theorem stating that topologies compatible with a duality share the same bounded sets, and treat reflexivity.

**Schechter**

- Start from an abstract dual pair $\langle E,F\rangle$: this is a completely algebraic construction. $E$ and $F$ are two vector spaces and $\langle,\rangle$ is a (separating) dual form.
- Describe polar topologies on $E$ or on $F$ in an analogous way as Treves. Now, however this is done through $\langle,\rangle$ and not the canonical evaluation of elements of the dual $E'$.
- Describe how the topology $\sigma(F,G)$ is the weakest making all the evaluations of elements of $G$ aigainst element of $F$ continuous, and gives both the result about the topology of equicontinuous convergence and the embedding in the double dual.

Now I ask:

- Are these two approaches completely equivalent?

It seems that, obviously, the Schechter's approach includes Treves by considering the canonical evaluation of a functional of $E'$ angainst an element of $E$.  Anyhow, I personally find Treves' discussion neater, and moreover all examples I encountered so far are of the type $<E,E'>$.

- But can this appproach be shown equivalent to the former?
- If we start from a dual pair $\langle F,G\rangle$ can we always
  recover all informations about it by considering some topology on $F$
  and $\langle F,F'\rangle$?
- If not which are the differences between the two?

What I can notice, at the algebraic level is the following rather straghtforwad fact

- A vector space $E$ and its algebraic dual $E^*$ form a dual pair
  $\langle E,E^*\rangle$ where the pairing bilinear map is given by the
  evaluation of linear functionals: $(x\in E, y\in E^*)\mapsto y(x)\in
     \mathbb{R}$.
- Conversely, given an arbitrary separating dual pair $\langle
     E,F\rangle$, we can notice that the bilinear form $\langle,\rangle$,
  a fixed $y\in F$ induces a linear map $x\mapsto <x,y>$ which is
  linear and injective. Hence it is an element of $E^*$ then $F$ can
  always  be indentified with a subspace of $E^*$.
  Or viceversa, with $E$ and $F^*$

Comment: Both approaches are equivalent. The advantage of starting with a dual pair of vector spaces is that you don't need to define any topology in advance. For instance, we can consider the duality between bounded measurable functions $M_b(T, \Sigma)$ and finite signed measures $ca(\Sigma)$ given by integration. If you however equip $M_b(X, \Sigma)$ with its usual supremum norm then its dual is much larger: it is the space $ba(\Sigma)$ of all finitely additive signed measures with bounded variation. So, if you just consider a dual pair, you don't need to care about identifying topological duals.

Comment: Now, considering the dual pair $\langle M_b, ca \rangle$ you can just speak of the weak topology $\sigma(M_b, ca)$ or the Mackey topology $\mu(M_b, ca)$ (or any other locally convex topology in between) which all are compatible with the dual pair, meaning that the dual of $M_b$ equipped with this topology is precisely what you want, namely the $ca$-space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dual pair $\langle E,F\rangle$ you can endow $E$ with the weak topology $\sigma(E,F)$ defined by the seminorms $$p_J(x)=\max\{|\langle x,y\rangle|: y\in J\}$$ for finite subsets $J$ of $F$. Then the linear map $\Phi:F\to (E,\sigma(E,F))'$, $y\mapsto \langle \cdot,y\rangle$ is a bijection (injective because the duality is separating, for the surjectivity you need a standard lemma: For all linear functionals $\phi,\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ on $E$ such that the intersection of the kernels of $\phi_i$ is contained in the kernel of $\phi$ you get $\phi$ as a linear combination of the $\phi_i$).

The advantage of general dual pairs is the symmetry. For example, if you have proved the theorem of bipolars that $B^{\circ\bullet}$ is the closed absolutely convex hull of $B\subseteq E$ (where $B^\circ$ is the polar in $E'$ and $M^\bullet$ is the polar in $E$) you get without further ado also the dual version that $M^{\bullet\circ}$ is the $\sigma(E',E)$-closed absolutely convex hull of $M\subseteq E'$.